# how to perform a union between two strings while preserving order and appropriate html tags

Tags: python

I have two texts. One is the original. The other is a modified version of the original: it has some words removed and html tags added to some words. Example:

```
orginal_text = "Pay me some good respect!"
modified_text = "Pay <span>some respect!</span>"
```

I'm looking to merge the two to add back the removed words and get the following:

```
Pay me <span>some</span> good <span>respect!</span>
```

In the example there was: `<span>some respect!</span>` but I want to put back `good` but not include it in the tag. So: `<span>some</span> good <span>respect!</span>`

Answer (score 2):

This works; mind you, if the "spanned" words in the modified_text appear elsewhere in the original text, this will not yield the expected result:

```
original_text = "Pay me some good respect!"
modified_text = "Pay <span>some respect!</span>"

sps, spe = '<span>', '</span>'
sptext = modified_text.split(sps)[1].split(spe)[0]
merged_text = original_text
for word in sptext.split():
    merged_text = merged_text.replace(word, sps+word+spe)
```

Result:

```
merged_text
Out[66]: 'Pay me <span>some</span> good <span>respect!</span>'
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The spanned words in the other samples I tried do appear elsewhere in the original text. Is there a way to avoid the unexpected result from happening?

Comment: It seems harder to identify the "wrong" occurences of these words from the right ones; I'll have to think about it.